# Why does mapping array expressible to itself produce error?

Tags: arrays, swift, array-map

I'm experimenting with this:

```
var orientations1: UIInterfaceOrientationMask = [.portrait, .landscapeRight]
var orientations2: UIInterfaceOrientationMask = [.portrait, .landscapeRight].map { $0 }
```

`orientations1` works fine, but `orientation2` produces the following error:

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

`UIInterfaceOrientationMask` conforms indirectly to `ExpressibleByArrayLiteral` protocol. How can `.map { $0 }` possibly change the contents of the array and what should I do to make it work?

**UPDATE**

Okay, so here's what I'm trying to do. I'm learning Swift and want to play with device orientation changing on runtime.

I have 4 switches:

```
@IBOutlet weak var switchPortrait: UISwitch!
@IBOutlet weak var switchLandscapeRight: UISwitch!
@IBOutlet weak var switchPortraitUpsideDown: UISwitch!
@IBOutlet weak var switchLandscapeLeft: UISwitch!

var orientationSwitches = [UISwitch]()
var orientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask = [.portrait, .landscapeRight, .landscapeLeft, .portrait]
```

In `viewDidLoad()` method, I'm doing this:

```
switchPortrait.tag  = Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait.rawValue)
switchLandscapeRight.tag = Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscapeRight.rawValue)
switchPortraitUpsideDown.tag   = Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portraitUpsideDown.rawValue)
switchLandscapeLeft.tag  = Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscapeLeft.rawValue)

orientationSwitches = [switchPortrait, switchLandscapeRight, switchPortraitUpsideDown, switchLandscapeLeft]

for switchElement in orientationSwitches {
    switchElement.isOn = orientations.contains(UIInterfaceOrientationMask(rawValue: UInt(switchElement.tag)))
}
```

So now every switch UI element has its tag set to appropriate orientation mask's raw value. Also, every switch is on or off, according to initial state of `orientations`.

On switching action, I'm trying to update `orientations` like this:

```
@IBAction func orientationSwitched(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    orientations = orientationSwitches.filter({ $0.isOn }).map({ UIInterfaceOrientationMask(rawValue: UInt($0.tag)) }) // doesn't work
}
```

But it doesn't work. And my `supportedInterfaceOrientations` looks simply like this:

```
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return orientations
}
```

I'm able to do it via `insert()` method for each UI switch element, but I want to learn if that can be done in more elegant way, by mapping.

Comment: `UIInterfaceOrientationMask` is an *OptionSet* and not an *Array*.  So, even though you can initialize it with an array literal, you cannot assign an array to it, which is what `map` returns.

Comment: Awful but works: `var orientations2: UIInterfaceOrientationMask = [UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait, .landscapeRight].map { $0 }.reduce(UIInterfaceOrientationMask()) { var result = $0; result.insert($1); return result }`

Comment: @vacawama, you can use `union` and `UIInterfaceOrientationMask()` can be replaced with `[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift, literals are typeless and their types are inferred depending on the contexts.

In your case, if Swift inferred the type of the array literal as `Array< UIInterfaceOrientationMask>`, you can apply `.map{ $0 }`, but the result also becomes `Array<UIInterfaceOrientationMask>` and cannot be converted to `UIInterfaceOrientationMask`. (See below.)

If Swift inferred the type of the array literal as `UIInterfaceOrientationMask`, then `map` is not available.

Thus, Swift cannot find any types matching to your declaration, which causes **`Type of expression is ambiguous without more context`**.

---

As you have been suggested in the comments of another thread, `ExpressibleByArrayLiteral` is used by the compiler to interpret the array literal according to the context. It does not mean arrays can automatically be converted to the type conforming to `ExpressibleByArrayLiteral`.

---

For **UPDATE**

As you see, `UIInterfaceOrientationMask` has no usual initializer taking an `Array`. So using `insert` is one steady way. Steady code would be more elegant than seemingly smart but fragile or hard-to-read codes.

If you insist on using *seemingly smart* code, you can write something like this:

```
@IBAction func orientationSwitched(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    orientations = orientationSwitches
        .filter{$0.isOn}
        .map{UIInterfaceOrientationMask(rawValue: UInt($0.tag))}
        .reduce([]) {$0.union($1)}
}
```

Comment: Is there something I could do? I want to map the array of some UI elements to `UIInterfaceOrientationMask` type via their `tag` property. In other words, each of my 4 UI elements represent different device orientation.

Comment: @RoboRobok, it's not clear enough what you really want to do. Add some sample code more specific and concrete.

Answer (score 2):

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Because `Map` function returns an `array` value as an output. So you need to change inferred type as an `array` like this to get the desired `map` function output.

```
let  orientations2: [UIInterfaceOrientationMask] = [.portrait, .landscapeRight].map { $0 }
```

Comment: `UIInterfaceOrientationMask` conforms to `ExpressibleByArrayLiteral` and can be expressed by array. I need `UIInterfaceOrientationMask` type, not `[UIInterfaceOrientationMask]`.

Comment: @RoboRobok, Your point make sense. But I thought if you just need to resolve that error. So you can define the inferred type as an array.

Comment: I included some more specific description of what I'm trying to do.